# Are questions that are migrated after the OP accepted an answer still considered accepted even if the OP doesn't have an account on Drupal Answers?

Tags: support

The question [What module should I use for showing mixed XML sources?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8476/what-module-should-i-use-for-showing-mixed-xml-sources) has been migrated, apparently, after the user accepted the given answer, and the user doesn't have an account on Drupal Answers.

Is the question considered answered, in this case, even if it has not been up-voted, and the user who accepted it doesn't have an account on DA?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this does carry through a migration.  Whichever answer was accepted stays accepted when a question is migrated...regardless of any owner's account status.

Comment: Thank you. Being in a site where the ratio of answered questions is important, I was wondering what happens in such cases; I thought the answer was shown as accepted, but the question was not counted as answered. I guess "Community ♦" is used as user who accepted the answer.